# Correct way of storing the "reach profile" of an object

Tags: data, geometry

We've got to store information about a diversity of mechanical "arms" that have a certain reach profile. We need to store the information about what kind of reach profile the arm has. Since there are a multitude of joints in the arms, the reach is not a perfect parabola, it could look as follows.

[image]

The porpuse of the data in our database is for a "webshop" to be able to filter on horizontal reach versus vertical reach. As you can imagine, when a certain vertical reach has been entered, there is only a certain horizontal reach on that height.

What would be the best format for storing this data? We're allowed to have a "resolution"-aspect of this, so the outcome of filtering this data does not have to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Without an explicit database system, I won't go into specific features that are available for managing geospatial data.

But it sounds like a simple coordinates table could serve your needs as well. Based on your example picture, it seems like the data you're referring to are just a set of X-Y coordinates. If so, then you can create an `ArmReachCoordinates` table like so (pseudo-code):

```
CREATE TABLE ArmReachCoordinates
(
    ArmId INT NOT NULL,
    VerticalReachPoint INT NOT NULL,
    HorizontalReachPoint INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ArmId, VerticalReachPoint, HorizontalReachPoint)
);
```

*Data types, especially for the reach point columns, will depend on the unit of measure and granularity you'll be storing.

Clustering the table on `(ArmId, VerticalReachPoint, HorizontalReachPoint)` would probably make sense (which depending on database system, would happen implicitly from the primary key). This would allow efficient querying when filtering on `ArmId`, or `ArmId` and `VerticalReachPoint`. Having an additional index on `(ArmId, HorizontalReachPoint)` could also make sense, should one ever want to query by `ArmId` and `HorizontalReachPoint`.

One would likely have an `Arms` table that stores the unique list of `Arms` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Arms
(
    ArmId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ArmName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ... -- Other distinct attributes about the Arms
)
```

This would be the parent table to your `ArmReachCoordinates` with a one-to-many relationship on `ArmId`.